# AngularFire2 Retrieve Child node Data As Object

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I want to retrieve data in child node as a Object using angularfire2

```
     getPostEditData(uid:any,key:any){

     this.dataObject = this.af.database.object('/webPosts/'+uid+key) as 
     FirebaseObjectObservable<postVal>
     return this.dataObject; }
```

I used this but its not working. How I suppose to do that?
[My Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7EUC.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another slash (`/`) with your reference.

```
getPostEditData(uid:any,key:any) {
    this.dataObject = 
        this.af.database.object('/webPosts/' + uid + '/' + key) as FirebaseObjectObservable<postVal>
    return this.dataObject; 
}
```

Wrong: `uid + key`

Right: `uid + '/' + key`